# To do or to doing?

Tags: verbs, gerunds

'Do you agree to participate in rehearsal and research shows and interact with technical equipment'?

I am wondering do I need to use 'interact with' or interacting with' here?

Comment: It's fine as it is. "Interacting" would require a preposition: _Do you agree to participate in rehearsal and research shows and **to** interacting with technical equipment_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either the Infinitive ***(interact)*** here,  or the Gerund with the preposition ***(to interacting)***.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary 
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agree :

***AGREE***

*transitive verb*

: to consent to as a course of action

// She agreed to sell him the house.

*intransitive verb*

: to accept or concede something (such as the views or wishes of another)

// agree to a plan.

Comment: In "She agreed to sell him the house", there is no direct object so "agree" is intransitive. "To sell him the house" is not a direct object, but an infinitival clause functioning as catenative complement of "agree". Dictionaries are hopeless at grammar, and MW is one of the worst. Objects are always noun phrases, as in "They agreed a price".